# ASP.Net core 2.2 web api - How to set JwtSecurityToken's audience as current requester's URL/Host for ajax calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on adding JWT based auth for a asp.net Core 2.2 web api.
As per my need, we need to support multiple audiences and domains.

Part of this i am able to setup TokenValidationParameters to register valid list of audiences, with below format:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = APIConstants.TokenIssuer,
        ValidAudiences = APIConstants.TokenAudience.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',').ToList(),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(APIConstants.TokenSecret))
    };
});

        // enabled CORS in api by this policy
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("GlablEnableCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(APIConstants.CorsAllowedForOrigins.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(','))
                   .WithMethods(APIConstants.CorsAllowedForMethods.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(','))
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

but while generating JWT token as per below, i am unable to get current client app's url(host) to set for audience property of JwtSecurityToken object.

```
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: APIConstants.TokenIssuer,
        // *audience: string.Concat(this.Request.Scheme, "://", this.Request.Host),//Tried this way, this too has same issue

        audience: "http://xxx-test",
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(APIConstants.TokenExpireAfter),
        signingCredentials: creds);
```

The client app which is requesting api for token, makes a plain jquery ajax call to endpoint which generates JwtSecurityToken and gives back.

*Here i don't know for what reason, but "Request.Host" or "Request.Host.Host" both for given api endpoint doesn't give me host/domain of client app which made ajax call to api.*

Am i missing some concept here? I was expecting one of these to give me client app's domain/host which i can then use to set audience while generating token.
**Is there any way my api endpoint can know which host invoked this ajax call?**

Please let me know if i need to bring more clarity to my question.

Thank you...

Comment: did you have any luck?